# Sticky nav on scroll, extend nav width from center

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a sticky navbar on scroll and I want to do two things when the navbar is "sticky" :

- I want to expand the nav width to 100vw (or 100%) from the center but I don't know how to do it
  I tried this :

```
.fixed-nav{
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   width:100vw;
}
```

- Also I want the nav to be positionned top 0

So I tried something and here is what I got but as you can see the nav width isn't expanded from the center and when the nav is positionned to top 0 there's an animation I don't really want : https://jsfiddle.net/Kiiara/65txkcyv/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altough your code is very messy. try using the following code for your 2 css selectors:

```
header{
    position:absolute;
    top:54px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    transition: .3s;
    z-index:500;
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: scaleX(0.95);
}

.heightHeader{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100vw;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

Comment: Indeed my code was very messy, so I changed it and removed all useless class, thanks for the review!

Answer (score 1):

if you change in your `.header` and `heightHeader` transition options like this

```
-webkit-transition: width 0.8s ease;
-moz-transition: width 0.8s ease;
-ms-transition: width 0.8s ease;
transition: width 0.8s ease;
```

you will only animate `width` property and container will expand from the center and you will avoid the animation of the `top`. The problem with smoothness begin inside where your menu stays with setted `margin-left: auto`. From my experience you cannot animate `auto` property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried your code and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. The animation was becuase to `transition` which is solved in this code. I have removed all animations because you said you don't want it.
2. `tranform-origin` will expand width from `center`.
3. No need to chnage `nav class` becuase you are already changing  `header`
4. See results in full page mode.

```js
// Sticky nav on scroll
const header = document.querySelector('header');
const nav = document.querySelector('#main');

const topOfNav = header.offsetTop;
function stickyNav() {
  if (window.scrollY >= topOfNav) {
    // Navbar's height
    header.classList.add('heightHeader');

  } else {
    header.classList.remove('heightHeader');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', stickyNav);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 54px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 95vw;
  transform-origin: center;
  z-index: 500;
}

.heightHeader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  transform-origin: center;

}

nav#main {
  height: 120px;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px #0000001A;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.fixed-nav .nav__menu {
  margin-left: auto;
}

nav#main .nav__logo {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.nav__menu {
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.nav__menu .main-menu-item {
  position: relative;
}

.main-menu-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin: 0 44px;
}

.main-menu-item:last-child {
  margin-left: 44px;
  margin-right: 342px;
}

.main-menu-item a {
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 2.8px;
}

section div {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <nav id="main">
        <div class="nav__logo"><a href="#">LOGO</a></div>

        <ul class="nav__menu">
          <li class="main-menu-item"><a href="#">One</a></li>
          <li class="main-menu-item"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
          <li class="main-menu-item"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
          <li class="main-menu-item"><a href="#">Four</a></li>
          <li class="main-menu-item"><a href="#">Five</a></li>
        </ul>

      </nav>
    </header>

    <section>
      <div>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est maiores debitis vel quam assumenda sunt harum, repellendus magnam in libero eveniet quibusdam soluta nobis molestias! Voluptates temporibus eius veritatis. Id.
        Eius nesciunt iure earum, assumenda aliquid aut! Quasi animi esse repudiandae sint ullam iusto inventore vero fugit officiis magni tempora, optio accusantium nobis libero, hic aspernatur impedit sapiente veniam numquam?
        Ex fugiat expedita hic id. Quibusdam assumenda natus, totam cum eos veniam esse! Officia, magnam itaque quisquam rem maxime eius voluptatem facilis quas, quidem est, eaque optio corporis exercitationem voluptate!
        Esse, modi? Eligendi eum, magni sunt voluptates dolor vel sapiente asperiores obcaecati similique eius nulla iste eveniet neque natus possimus inventore quas nobis alias assumenda excepturi? Repudiandae deleniti voluptatem dicta.
        Accusamus impedit quasi at autem eos, molestiae beatae mollitia. Magnam labore ea quis facilis. A cupiditate minus, error maxime ullam fugiat quam numquam dicta quidem tempore labore veniam optio magnam?
        Odio ullam perspiciatis qui recusandae officiis voluptatibus nisi dolore ad sequi maxime, iusto nostrum assumenda, repellendus est ab quas soluta dolorem, voluptate quam eos delectus. Laborum, laboriosam harum. Pariatur, aspernatur!
        Deleniti commodi illum minima dolorum animi. Qui, exercitationem architecto sunt molestiae assumenda, reiciendis quaerat at iusto earum nulla porro officia? Animi possimus, tempore maxime libero esse labore quam minima ipsa?
        Totam earum illo molestias inventore unde veritatis officia, quia modi impedit nisi odio ducimus voluptatibus itaque explicabo est neque accusamus fuga, laudantium autem debitis nulla minus ab? Nesciunt, natus fugiat.
        Perspiciatis suscipit obcaecati veniam in praesentium earum repellat iste amet fuga voluptate, nesciunt, quisquam necessitatibus molestiae natus rerum itaque incidunt. Officiis consectetur voluptatem non beatae sequi inventore nihil adipisci iure!
        Provident ab excepturi alias aperiam tempora dignissimos nostrum, maxime debitis atque. Vero unde libero aut sint doloribus deleniti rem sed beatae maxime dolore laboriosam veniam maiores, natus quod facere molestias!
        Accusantium tempore voluptate corporis non voluptatibus, necessitatibus quas, nemo quos officiis accusamus impedit repudiandae sunt consequatur recusandae blanditiis vel atque sequi quis deserunt explicabo tenetur labore qui commodi. In, inventore!
        Maiores mollitia asperiores non provident. Nisi quas unde vel aliquam odit eos nesciunt nostrum dignissimos harum tempore magnam saepe iusto inventore ullam aut similique nam nobis, quia impedit ipsam beatae.
        Enim sed ducimus molestias debitis accusantium, sint laboriosam minima perferendis corrupti dolorum consequatur voluptatem ab aspernatur numquam consectetur temporibus quo nesciunt quam aliquid. Itaque cumque voluptate quos minima illo cum!
        Cumque autem labore aut ipsam repellendus vero eaque eligendi? Cupiditate perferendis quos at aliquid deleniti. Incidunt temporibus aut, officiis nam deleniti quisquam labore autem dolorum unde illum perspiciatis rerum quod!
        Harum, eveniet repellendus dicta, quod nesciunt natus maxime rem in, ab expedita exercitationem modi. Laudantium, minus reiciendis cum, dolorum distinctio tempore aliquam quidem dicta doloribus rerum sequi sunt pariatur voluptas?
        Distinctio ullam debitis, aliquam hic vitae aut doloribus provident sint soluta expedita repudiandae, et qui, earum omnis impedit perferendis. Hic omnis ab blanditiis ea ad nesciunt cupiditate laudantium adipisci aliquid.
        Culpa iusto, quam repudiandae sapiente reiciendis, nulla, quod quisquam quidem excepturi saepe dolorum velit est ex vero ipsam? Exercitationem architecto assumenda aliquam sequi dolore excepturi facere repellat animi ab magni.
        Eum provident culpa, ut natus, minus sequi, nobis illo sit quia corporis architecto! Iure atque culpa sint, ratione libero pariatur nemo, quidem dolorem, deleniti numquam cupiditate explicabo accusamus maiores eligendi?
        Nobis, eos porro quod neque adipisci explicabo quo fugit modi veniam mollitia delectus, ipsam illum? Facere qui magni officiis voluptas voluptate tempora recusandae reiciendis dolore sequi officia, harum laboriosam at.
        Cumque beatae, consectetur voluptate eligendi quaerat, esse labore obcaecati, quisquam dolor deserunt mollitia tempora. Cum, voluptatum? Veniam, iusto repellat. Quo aliquid perferendis quasi nisi consequuntur explicabo ut dolorem exercitationem perspiciatis!</div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </section>
```